# When does the inverse of $A^2+b I$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

The inverse of the matrix $\widetilde{A} = A^2 + b^2 I$ comes up in an equation of my work, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $b>0$ and $I$ is the $n$-dimensional identity matrix. Now I would like to know what conditions $A$ has to satisfy s.t. the inverse of $\widetilde{A}$ exists and maybe see a few different approaches to answer this.

My attempt:

The inverse does *not* exist iff $-b^2$ is equal to an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Because the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$, the matrix is not invertible iff the condition
$$\pm i b = \lambda$$
is satisfied, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Because $b>0$, the above given condition can only be met when at least one eigenvalue of $A$ is purely imaginary. Therefore if $A$ has no purely imaginary eigenvalues, matrix $\widetilde{A}$ is invertible for all $b>0$. For the general case, $\widetilde{A}$ is invertible for almost all $b>0$ (where for at most $n$ different values of $b$ the inverse does not exist).

Is this a valid explanation?

Comment: I fail to see why this question got closed. Although short in words, I believe it's clear what I want and I show my own effort in the answer section. Can someone explain, what I did wrong?

Comment: First of all, short questions without any context nor showing your own tries are not welcome. Also, the verb "want" is not polite. Second, you should put your efforts in the question, not in an answer. Last, after your editing of the question, it is collecting reopen votes and probably it would be reopen soon.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm sorry about the "want"-part. No excuse but I was in a hurry and did not check my writing. I will try to remember your points in the future.